# How do I upgrade libraries in Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 as a virtual machine. During installation of a previously installed library in the terminal, I found I have 274 packages not upgraded.

How do I upgrade them?

Do I have to upgrade them one by one?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get upgrade`. What happens?

Comment: so i delete it? i am new here so i dont know

Comment: You needn't delete it. It's useful as a sign-post to those who search for something like this.

Answer (score -1):

This will automatically update your package:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```